# TypeScript definition for factory function

Tags: typescript

I'm seeking guidance on creating a class declaration in a .d.ts file.

The class has a method that accepts a typeof T and returns an instance of T.

Comment: Take a look at the `WidgetFactory` example http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files-examples. If you already have a `.ts` code for the class with the factory method... then just use the `--declaration` command line option of the `tsc` compiler and it will spit out the `.d.ts` file for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need something that is *creatable* and then its smooth sailing:

```
interface Creator<T> {
    new (): T;
}
function factory<T>( arg: Creator<T> ): T {
    return new arg();
}


// Usage: 
class Foo {
    something = 123;
}
var foo = factory( Foo ); // foo:Foo
```